# AS3 - Searching An Array for the items that contains a particular word when each item is a paragraph long

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, arrays

bit new to AS3 so forgive me if this is a bit of a straight forward question.

Ive created an array, and each item in the array is a description of something, about 20 words long, I want to search the array, and return each item that contains a particular word.

All the other tutorials Ive found are based on looping through to search for an exact match.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

No matter what, you'll need to iterate through the array to find the match.

This said, use the `String.search()` method to look for your word:

```
var searchTerm:String = "whatever word you're looking for";
var foundItems:Array = new Array();

for each(var paragraph:String in paragraphArray) {
    if(paragraph.search(searchTerm) != -1) {
        foundItems.push(paragraph);
    }
}
return foundItems;
```

---

**EDIT**:
I tested with the following code, and it seemed to work ok.

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" creationComplete="filterArray()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private var arr:Array = ["a", "a b c", "c d e", "a d e", "z q aaa r"];
            private var searchF:String = "a";

            private function filterArray():void {
                var searchTerm:String = searchF;

                for each(var paragraph:String in arr) {
                    if(paragraph.search(searchTerm) != -1) {
                        trace('found: ' + paragraph);
                    }
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Application>
```

**Edit #2**: I modified the previous snippet so it looked more like what you had in your comment.  I broke out "searchF" and pointed to it from `searchTerm` in `filterArray()`.

Comment: Thanks for all of the answers. Ive tried putting this in, made a couple of changes, but it doesnt get past the       if(paragraph.search(searchTerm) != -1) { line.

Here is what ive done, searchf being the variable holding the search term, and arr my array to search. It wont trace out 2.

function searchFeeds(){
var foundItems:Array = new Array();
var searchTerm:String = searchf;

trace("1")
for each(var paragraph:String in arr) { 
 if(paragraph.search(searchTerm) != -1) {
  trace("2");
        foundItems.push(paragraph);
    }
}
return foundItems;

Thanks Again!

Answer (score 1):

The only efficient way to do what you want is a lookup table (these can get complicated, before you embark on this, do some performance tests - the brute force search approaches listed here may work fine for you).

The basic idea is that you keep a list of all the paragraphs where a particular word occurred. So, if "foobar" appeared in paragraphs 1, 2, and 7, we would want the following to be true:

```
myLookupTable["foobar"] = [1,2,7];
```

If we do this for every word in every paragraph, we get a nice little list.

This is the basic idea:

```
var myHugeArray:Array = // fill your array data in here

var lookup:Object = {};

// Now we iterate through each item in your array and index all the words that we find
for (var idx:int in myHugeArray)
{
    var par:String = myHugeArray[idx] as String;
    par = par.replace(/['",.;:-()!?]/g, " "); // remove common punctuation

    var words:Array = par.split(" ");  // split the paragraph into specific words
    for each(var word:String in words) 
    {
        if(lookup[word] == undefined}
            lookup[word] = [];
        lookup[word].push(idx); // record the index of the paragraph that contained the word
    }
}

// now do search for a word
var results:Array = lookup["foobar"];
if(results != null)
{
    for each(var idx:int in results)
        trace("Hit!", myHugeArray[idx]);
}
```

Now, you have to update your lookup table whenever you add or remove items from the array (not shown here). In addition, you may want to create a "stop list" of common words such as "the" and "a" that aren't indexed. Finally, this will only return *exact* matches on words. If you want to be able to type in "foob" and still get hits for "foobar", then you need to create within-word indexes, which are much more complex and memory-intensive.

Answer (score 0):

`filter`

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Array.html#filter%28%29

```
var myArray = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'cac'];
var needle = 'a';
trace( myArray.filter(array_search) );


function array_search(element:*, index:int, arr:Array):Boolean {
    return (element.indexOf(needle) > -1 ? true : false);
}
```